# gdaldem hillshade stop working with new projection?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, hillshade, mercator, gdaldem

Parallel to [gdalwarp `-te -5.8 41 10 51.5 -ts 1980 0` not working with mercator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137167/) , my hillshade works with lat/long input :

```
gdaldem hillshade input.tmp.tif shadedrelief.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges
```

But stopped to work when input is in mercator :

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857  input.tmp.tif reproj.tmp.tif #mercator
gdaldem hillshade reproj.tmp.tif shadedrelief.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges
```

While lat/long is in degree, mercator is in meters, I believe both z scales to be in `m` which requires `-s 111120` (requires `-s 370400` if in feet!). Also, **what do I do wrong ?**

Comment: Simple, remove the `-s` scale option for projected rasters.

Comment: Works... But Why? why, why..... <coding>

Comment: Seems mercator need `-s 1`, equal to no `-s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale option is only needed for "unprojected" rasters with units in degrees. It is the ratio of height units used in the DEM (typically meters) to distance units in degrees.

So for Mercator or other projected rasters, you can ignore the scale option, or use the default of 1 (no scale).

Comment: So, as a good practice, should I always reproject my source ? and will it change to meters if I reproject from lat/lon to lat/long. (your are not required to answer that but if you know it's a good add)

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing with the data. I generally keep the originals, e.g. SRTM data are lat/long.

Comment: Yeah, I use SRTM to do [this](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/1.2_location_map/index.html) (work in progress, hillshade coming within minutes :) ), all done via make script. Point is, as I don't want to balance between `-s 111120` and `-s 1`, if I can have a trick to always have my input in meters it would ease my use case.

Comment: The scale option is needed if vertical and horizontal units are *different*. Most usual case is just the degrees/meters case but other combinations are possible as well, like feet/meters.